# new in java method and return

Tags: java, methods, return

i have a question. i have to create 3 methods testUreaRisk, testProteinRisk and printResults. and the below is 2 out of the 3.

```
public class Lab {


        public static String testUreaRisk(double ureaLevel)
        {
            if ((ureaLevel < 0) || (ureaLevel > 10))
                return "0";
            else if (ureaLevel <= 4.0)
                return "-1";
            else 
                return "1";
        }

        public static String testProteinRisk(double proLevel)
        {
            if ((proLevel < 0) || (proLevel >150))
                return "0";
            else if (proLevel >= 67.0)
                return "1";
            else 
                return "-1";

        }
```

so my problem is can i put a value into the return number 1, 0,-1 as -1 = low risk, 0 = cannot be defined and 1 = high risk? if can,how? because the 3rd method could only allow me to return a string that show the result (low risk,cannot be defined and high risk) instead of the number(-1,0,1).thanks

Comment: You can create an enum instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But better way is use an `Enum`.

Eg:

```
  public enum Enum {
   LOW("-1"), NOT_DETERMINED("0"), HIGH("1");

  }
```

Eg:

My `Enum` class

```
public enum Enum {
    LOW("-1"), NOT_DETERMINED("0"), HIGH("1");
    private String code;
    private Enum(String c) {
        this.code = c;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public static Enum getEnum(String code) {
        switch (code) {
            case "-1":
                return LOW;
            case "0":
                return NOT_DETERMINED;
            case "1":
                return HIGH;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now

```
System.out.println(Enum.getEnum(testProteinRisk(10)));
```

Will give you

```
LOW
```

Comment: i could not change the testUreaRisk and testProteinRisk return value as the question wants me to return it in the integers. Only the third method wants to show the result instead of the integers.

Comment: @NoahSkullWeijian then you should go with the `Enum`

Comment: @NoahSkullWeijian  See my example.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with an Enum class here. If you want to have int values, you could create in each enum a emthod that will re`enter code hereturn this value:)

```
Enum { LOW(-1), NOT_DETERMINED(0), HIGH(1);
 // getters
 }
```